# mongodb - how to filter multiple column

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have some documents in my collection like below

```
{
  "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "Keyword Group A": [
    "Facebook",
    "Twitter"
  ],
  "Keyword Group B": [
    "Netflix"
  ]
},
 {
  "_id": "yyyyyyy",
  "Keyword Group A": [
    "Twitter"
  ],
  "Keyword Group B": [
    "Instagram",
  ],
  ...
}
```

I can fetch all documents whose `Keyword Group A` contains "Facebook", by below filter

```
    $filter: {
      input: "$Keyword Group A",
      as: "group",
      cond: { $eq: ["$$group", "Facebook"] },
    }
```

But If I want to fetch all documents if `Keyword Group A` contains "Facebook" **OR** `Keyword Group B` contains "Instagram", how should I adjust the filters?

Comment: Is this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qn8jHpKkPqf) meet your requirement?

Comment: @CCCC Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to use `$filter` because your requirement will fulfill just by equal to a condition in `$match` stage or in query,

```
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "Keyword Group A": "Facebook"
        },
        {
          "Keyword Group B": "Instagram"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8rA2vBYql40)